# Wordpress sort by value from specific table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to get 4 posts in order by 'pageviews' from a plugin named Wordpress Popular posts. I found in phpmyadmin where it stores the page views per post. My problem is that the values for 'pageviews' for the post is not in the wp_postmeta but in a separate table: wp_popularpostdata and named pageviews. Please help :)

phpmyadmin

from wp_popularpostdata

postid | pageviews

..1..............14

the code below I'm trying returns nothing

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'meta_key' => pageviews,
        'orderby' => meta_value_num,
        'order' => DESC,
    );
                $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the built-in function `wpp_get_mostpopular` as explained [here](https://github.com/cabrerahector/wordpress-popular-posts/wiki/2.-Template-tags#wpp_get_mostpopular):

```
if (function_exists('wpp_get_mostpopular'))
    wpp_get_mostpopular("range=weekly&order_by=comments");
```

If it isn't sufficient to you, you'll have to alter the query through wordpress filters like `posts_join`, `posts_where` and etc. The [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_join) should help you to find the way.

Comment: How can I implement this in $my_query?
Im planning to use this before the code if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

Comment: You should implement this *instead of* using $my_query and WP_Query at all. To use $my_query you will have to use a filter to alter the join clause (to make at least a left join with the plugin table) and another filter to alter the order by clause (to order by the number you want from the plugin's table). Altering $my_query is a solution too much harder ;)

Comment: Is there any easier way/alternatives? All I want is to get the four titles of 4 posts with the four highest values of 'pageviews' in the table wp_popularpostdata.

Comment: It's just remove your previous code, add `if (function_exists('wpp_get_mostpopular'))
    wpp_get_mostpopular("limit=4&post_html='{title}'");` and style the result :)

Comment: Almost there :) , how can I put each title as <li>? Because it's the style. My original code was: if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
     <li class="trendingPost <?php if($i % 4 == 0){echo 'last';} ?>">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php mts_short_title('...', 24); ?></a>
     </li>

Comment: Just alter `{title}` to `<li class=\"trendingPost\">{title}</li>`. For the `last` class style unfortunatelly you'll have to use `:nth-child(4n)` in the css files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104454/discussion-between-jeffrey-nerona-and-felipe-elia).